# Font Identification for a futuristic tech-looking font

Tags: font-identification

It's a font from the future, but I don't know what it will be called! Can anyone help?

Tried WhatTheFont, was unsuccessful...posted up a case there, so if I get an answer there I'll post it here.

[image]

Comment: It may be from the future, but it's spent a while in the late 80s!

Comment: Also, upvote for actually putting something more useful than "what's this font?" in the question heading!

Comment: Reminds me of the AirWolf logo. Thanks for giving me a nostalgic laugh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some research on [www.dafont.com](http://www.dafont.com) and your font looks like a modified version of [N-Gage](http://www.dafont.com/n-gage.font?text=INNOVATIVE).

[image: N-Gage Innovative Example]

The "A" is different, and bears more similarity to [Venus Rising](http://www.dafont.com/venus-rising.font?text=INNOVATIVE).  I included both, since the N-Gage "A" is kind of weird and you may not like it.

Comment: I'm wondering if `N-Gage` is actually a modified font from another font though...

Comment: @Johannes Well - hard to say, but the [Nokia N-Gage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Gage_%28device%29) is an actual device, which bears the same font.  Nokia could have bought it and modified it, but it seems more plausible to me that it was the original since I'd expect Nokia to have commissioned a new design.

Comment: Odds are the logo was designed independently, then someone on their own decided to turn into into a full typeface.